# MySQL Stored Pocedures skip WHERE condition if parameter is null

Tags: mysql, search, stored-procedures, multiple-columns

I'm writing stored procedure that should search for records base on few procedure arguments. 
The problem is that not always all arguments have to be passed, sometimes they may be set to NULL.

Is there a way to write sth that would work like that?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(IN p_idWorker INTEGER, IN p_idEffect INTEGER)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        CallHistory
    WHERE
        idWorker = IFNULL(p_idWorker, ANYTHING)
        AND 
        idEffect = IFNULL(p_idEffect, ANYTHING);
END$$
```

Comment: Not really Sashi - there's no keyword like 'ANYTHING' in MySQL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thank you Mahmoud and valex for your time but both answers are not totally good. They will not work if for example the field `idWorker` is nullable - it will not see the rows where field `idWorker IS NULL`.

The ultimate solution to this looks weird but it works:

```
...
WHERE 
    idWorker = IFNULL(p_idWorker, idWorker)
    AND
    IFNULL(ch.idProjTime, -1) = IFNULL(p_idProjTime, IFNULL(ch.idProjTime, -1))
```

Now it'll see `NULL` fields too.

If it is bad idea to sth like that (I can see probable performance impact - 3 times a row it does the `IFNULL` condition) - please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
 ...
 WHERE (p_idWorker IS NULL OR idWorkder = p_idWorker)
   AND (p_idEffect IS NULL OR idEffect = p_idEffect);
```

Or, like the way you did, but instead of `Anything` use the column name instead like so:

```
   ...
   WHERE
        idWorker = IFNULL(p_idWorker, idWorker )
        AND 
        idEffect = IFNULL(p_idEffect, idEffect );
```

Comment: First one wouldnt work, cause it would select rows where idWorker is NULL even if I would set p_idWorker parameter. Second one is great though and you were first so 'solution' mark goes to you. Thx.

Comment: After some tests I have to revoke accept unfortunately. It is not going to work when for example column idWorker is NULL by default. All those rows that has NULL in this column will not be seen by the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example:

```
    idWorker = IFNULL(p_idWorker, idWorker)
```

IF `p_idWorker is null` then this condition is always `TRUE` for all rows. If not then it is true only if `idWorker = p_idWorker`

Comment: It's good answer but you were second so would be not justice to give you solution mark, but +1 for you. Thank you.

Comment: It seems after some tests that it's not good solution - see my 2nd comment under Mahmoud Gamal answer.